# How to automatic reset linux vm at every boot time

Tags: virtual-machines

I am working on virtual linux based penetration testing lab.
I have configured debian linux according to my requirements and lab (like apache, mysql, firewall, network, permissions, etc), I just want to automatically reset the vm at every boot to the same configuration made by me. All the changes made during the penetration testing should be discard.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what virtualization platform you're using, but most of the common ones have the ability to "snapshot" a VM - essentially a point-in-time image of the machine that can be rolled back to at will.

Keep in mind that this increases disk space usage dramatically and snapshots are not a form of backup.  However, for situations such as yours, they make rollback to a known good point in time very easy.

Comment: i can use virtual box or vmware , which one work better for me for this ?

Comment: Both have snapshot functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want automatically reset your virtual machine to an original configuration you have to configure each VM virtual disk as immutable/not persistent (different hypervisors call this feature in different ways).
In this link it's explained how enable this feature in virtual box and vmware https://srikeshs.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/how-to-make-a-virtual-disk-non-persistent-or-immutable/ .
Enabling this feature the disk will be restored to the original configuration automatically when reboot or shutdown the virtual machine.

You can also use snapshot as recommended in other answer but it has a different behaviour. The snapshot feature allows to save an image of the virtual machine and restore the snapshot image only when you need it. You have to execute some commands on your hypervisor in order to reset the virtual machine state, reboot the virtual machine isn't enough to restore the VM original state.